# How to `require` a file without printing out its top level expressions?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

File `a.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(provide f)
(define (f) 10)
(f)
```

File `b.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(require "a.rkt")
```

Then when I run `b.rkt`, I will get `f` which is what I want. But a `10` will also be printed in my REPL which I don't want.

How can I `require` file `a.rkt` without the `10` printed on my REPL?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose your call to `f` in a `module` clause in `a.rkt`:

```
#lang racket
(provide f)
(define (f) 10)
(module+ main
  (f))
```

The forms in the `module+ main` part will only be executed when you run `a.rkt` directly, not when you `require` it.

For more info see [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._main-and-test%29).